# how to debug remotely TCL codes from solaris / linux ? and is there any eclipse plugin for doing this?

Tags: tcl, remote-debugging

I was trying to remote debug the (i)TCL code written for solaris10 and SuSE10. I tried active tcl and remote wrapper method. But the iTCL part I was not able to debug.

Is there any method so that I can debug the tcl codes remotely?

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128853/how-to-monitor-applications-being-open-or-launch-in-linux-tcl-python/14130913#14130913 related?

Comment: no, i want a debugging option for remote debugging the iTCL codes. please help..